# Updating SQL Parent/Child Table records with #Temp Table comparison

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server question I was hoping someone might be able to assist me with. I have the following parent-child table structure. The `PID` value in the Parent table is the primary key (identity). The Primary key in the child table is a combined `PID` and `CVal1` (where `PID` in the Child table is a foreign key to the Parent table). As shown, the child table can have multiple records for each `PID` in the parent table.

```
Parent Table
+-----+-------+-------+
| PID | Pval1 | Pval2 |
+-----+-------+-------+
|  99 |    45 |   126 |
| 100 |    45 |   155 |
| 101 |    33 |    12 |
+-----+-------+-------+

Child Table    
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| PID | CVal1 | Cval2 | Cval3 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  99 |    18 |    15 |    10 |
|  99 |     5 |    15 |    10 |
| 100 |    12 |    12 |    15 |
| 101 |    14 |    11 |    11 |
| 101 |    15 |     9 |     7 |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Often, the table contents are updated for a set of records with a particular `Pval1` (e.g. for `Pval1` = 45; the first 2 records of the Parent Table and the first 3 records of the Child table may change). Initially, I deleted all associated records in both tables and then added the new contents; However, now the idea is to only delete/add what has actually changed. I have two Temp tables #TempParent and #TempChild (with identical strictures) that hold the updated content.

I want to compare the temp tables to the permanent tables and INSERT where not exists in the permanent tables and DELETE where not exists in the Temp tables for a particular `Pval1`. Since the `PID` in the Temp tables won't match up with the permanent tables, I'm going to have to compare on `Pval1`, `Pval2`, `Cval1`, `Cval2`, and `Cval3`. But I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Does anyone have an idea on how I might be able to go about this? I really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't just apply the updates to the actual tables in a Transaction where you can rollback need be, but here's the script for the ParentTable. Same concepts will apply for Child if you need it, just let me know.

Here you go:

```
SELECT * INTO ParentTable
FROM
(
    SELECT 99 AS PID, 45 AS Pval1, 126 AS Pval2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 100,45,155
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,33,12
) A;

 SELECT *
 FROM ParentTable;
```

Original ParentTable:

```
PID         Pval1       Pval2
----------- ----------- -----------
99          45          126
100         45          155
101         33          12
```

Pretend my #TempParent is updated data where one row is deleted, one row is inserted, and one row is unchanged:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempParent
FROM
(
    SELECT 200 AS PID, 200 AS Pval1, 200 AS Pval2 --inserted row
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 101,33,12 --kept row
) A;
```

Now for the delete and insert statements:

```
DELETE
FROM ParentTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS    (
                    SELECT Pid,Pval1,Pval2 
                    FROM #TempParent 
                    WHERE #TempParent.Pid = ParentTable.PID
                    AND #TempParent.Pval1 = ParentTable.Pval1
                    AND #TempParent.Pval2 = ParentTable.Pval2
                    );

INSERT INTO ParentTable
SELECT *
FROM #TempParent
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   
                    SELECT Pid,Pval1,Pval2 
                    FROM ParentTable
                    WHERE ParentTable.Pid = #TempParent.PID
                    AND ParentTable.Pval1 = #TempParent.Pval1
                    AND ParentTable.Pval2 = #TempParent.Pval2
                );
```

Compare your tables(which should match):

```
SELECT *
FROM ParentTable

SELECT *
FROM #TempParent

PID         Pval1       Pval2
----------- ----------- -----------
101         33          12
200         200         200

PID         Pval1       Pval2
----------- ----------- -----------
101         33          12
200         200         200
```